# Marquee Text Android Not Working

Tags: android, text, marquee

Here My Layout and i dont know why not working i already search for answer but still cannot run , i already test to add scroll too but still cannot

Here my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">




        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="5px"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/layout_b"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="80px"
                android:src="@drawable/home"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/info_text"
               />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
            </TableRow>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




</LinearLayout>
```

Whats wrong with my code ? anyone pls help

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Change your `wrap_content` value to `match_parent` or fixed width.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

Or

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    />
```

#### Solution 2

Try to use below code after your view rendered.

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```